# how to set proper types in axios request for array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I'm trying to write a axios service for api requests and I have a problem with understanding this error:

> Type 'AxiosResponse<User[]>' is missing the following properties from
> type 'User[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2740) const
> response: AxiosResponse<User[]>

My code looks like that:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import User from 'src/models/User';

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
});

export async function getAllUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
  const response = await http.get<User[]>('users/');
  return response;
}

export async function getSingleUser(itemId: string): Promise<User> {
  const response = await http.get<User>(`/${itemId}`);
  return response;
}
```

For sure I'm not understading some basic typescript concept. Can u help me?

How this should be done if the response will be wrapped in 'data' poperty?

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is the fact that the axios functions (such as `get`) return an `AxiosInstance` and not the actual object you expect. you should access the `data` property of the `AxiosInstance` to get the value you're expecting:

```
export async function getAllUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
  const response = await http.get<User[]>('users/');
  return response.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the `res.data` for `http.get()` method, see [Response Schema](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)

```
import axios from 'axios';

interface User {}

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
});

export async function getAllUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
  const response = await http.get<User[]>('users/').then(res => res.data)
  return response;
}

export async function getSingleUser(itemId: string): Promise<User> {
  const response = await http.get<User>(`/${itemId}`);
  return response;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZzgMyhEcDkyqa+A3AFDnAB2MAplJggMZ1wCqaDcA3gL6VmEamngALGDDBwAvIhToAdMyh0E9ABQ9ycOACMEXdgCUAMgC4CEqeYD0tgDYRmCB2PQxzAZgAMf-AA0OnBiagAmDGiWPAQAwsL0tAC0ACoAnmB0+JaEYGAOwC4wqNS2AFZowvhwfEF8AJQU5HRIkLCIaGnUzFgArt3FwnAA5nQwAIIODpyRGvWWAAo4IMBcADwzUADaALoAfLzBQiLwqmiQImxyCADuCMDikmCKozAbXNv7Gvi9H2i2+HqihgoWoGjOsgOZ0UYXUCHqwVUMF6UGocDOFy4FAEzVa0Hghi6PUw-WYgzRrwAyjRhg46JsNA86CAAJJhSyiKA0+ZwJa4VZ0d4MA7aXTHUToujnYRcWSIO4PEJPF5jIVQPYaAAGtgAJDwmaywnxNY1EWMUWiMTK6NigA)